# Problems identifying "click-point" and subplot clicked in JfreeChart Plot

Tags: java, plot, jframe, mouseevent, jfreechart

I've spent several days trying to solve it but it seems to be more complicated than expected.

I have an App which has a tree of Jframes as structure (as usual); in this tree, i have a sub-structure which looks like this:

MyPanel (extends JPanel) contains:
       MyChartPanel (extends ChartPanel) contains:
               FreeChart chart => CombinedDomainXYPlot - globalPlot contains:
                       Several XYPlots

I've put "Prints" so i can see where the user (me, so far) is clicking or moving the mouse over. I don't know why, just a sub-area of the total area of the subplots say "it's me". I mean, just a sub-rectangle tells me is that plot, though i can see the subplot is bigger, but it i click or move the mouse too much to the right extreme, there is no answer from any subplot.

There is a constant distance from the left side towards the right in wich i can certainly get the subplot clicked, but from that "vertical frontier", i click and i get no subplot, even when al least there is a 15 - 20 % more of subplot to the right.

I have no problems with the "top-down" direcctions, just with the 15-20% of the right side.

If i make smaller the App window so its width is equal or shorter than that constant distance, then i can click at the right extreme of the subplot without problems; it tells me is X subplot perfectly.

Even if i haven't add any other plot but the main one, i have this same problem when trying to identify the subplot (the only one) i'm clicking.

I'm not asking for the solution, but fot ideas of what could be the problem, because i'm runnig out of them.

Thanks.

Comment: have you reduced this to an SSCCE http://sscce.org/ we can try out?

Comment: Thanks Andersoj; trying to do as you asked me to; reducing the code size (which is huge) to paste something more or less clean, i've realized that at some moment i commented everywhere the part of code i use to translate the coordinates from screen to Java2D, so un-commenting it in the part i thought it should actually be, everything works fine again.

Comment: Thanks Andersoj; trying to do as you asked me to; reducing the code size (which is huge) to paste something more or less clean, i've realized that at some moment i commented everywhere the part of code i use to translate the coordinates from screen to Java2D, so un-commenting it in the part i thought it should actually be, everything works fine again.

Hope my situation be useful if someone makes a similar error.

Anyway, since your answer has helped me in realizing it, your comment is at least a "great comment" for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i had commented accidentally the code i used to translate the coordiantes from the screen to Jav2D.

Hope having posted my error saves some time to someone.